# HLSL: the modulus of a dispatch thread ID returns a different value than a normal uint?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl, compute-shader

For `id.x = 70` this returns 3:

```
RWStructuredBuffer<int> _TestBuffer;
. . . 
_TestBuffer[id.x] = floor(id.x / 5) % 5;
```

However this returns 4 as expected:

```
_TestBuffer[id.x] = floor(70 / 5) % 5;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested, I tried using `round()` like so:

```
floor(round(id.x) / 5) % 5;
```

Which still returns a value of 3 for `id.x = 70`. However, after playing with it for a while I found that changing the data type of  `_TestBuffer` from `int` to `float` returned the correct value of 4 and was a big clue in figuring out what was going wrong:

```
RWStructuredBuffer<float> _TestBuffer;
. . . 
_TestBuffer[id.x] = floor(id.x / 5) % 5;
//This returns 4 for _TestBuffer[70]
```

So here is what is causing the bug:

1. The `floor(id.x / 5)` function returns a `float`
2. Because it is a `float` the modulo operation `14 % 5` returns a floating point number, probably something like `3.99999`
3. That number is implicitly converted to type `int` when it is assigned to `_TestBuffer[id.x]`
4. As per the rules for [conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/casting-and-conversion) in HLSL, `3.99999` is rounded towards zero, resulting in an `int` value of `3`

The solution for the bug is simply to round the the expression before assignment like so:

```
RWStructuredBuffer<int> _TestBuffer;
. . . 
_TestBuffer[id.x] = round(floor(id.x / 5) % 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id.x` is `69.999999` (might be a result of coordinate calculation),

`floor(id.x / 5)` will be 13 instead of 14, thus:

`floor(id.x / 5) % 5` will be 3 and not 4 as expected.

To solve the problem round id.x before calculation:

```
_TestBuffer[id.x] = (round(id.x) / 5) % 5;
```